# Grep multiple strings containing regex

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to print specific lines out of an XML (Input_file.txt) that looks like this (each tag in a new line)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
 <INVOIC02>
 <IDOC>
 <EDI_DC40>
 <DOCNUM/>
 <DOCREL/>
 <IDOCTYP>INVOIC02</IDOCTYP>
 <CIMTYP/>
 <MESTYP>INVOIC</MESTYP>
 <SNDPOR>SAPP01</SNDPOR>
 <SNDPRT/>
 <SNDPFC/>
 <SNDPRN>ALE400</SNDPRN>
 <SNDSAD/>
 <SNDLAD/>
 <RCVPOR>XMLINVOICE</RCVPOR>
 <RCVPRT>KU</RCVPRT>
 </EDI_DC40>
 </IDOC>
 </INVOIC02>
```

I would like my output to be the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
 <EDI_DC40>
 <DOCNUM/>
 <IDOCTYP>INVOIC02</IDOCTYP>
 <MESTYP>INVOIC</MESTYP>
 <SNDPOR>SAPP01</SNDPOR>
 </EDI_DC40>
 </IDOC>
 </INVOIC02>
```

I'm able to print a specific line this way, example

```
 grep '^.*<IDOCTYP>.*</IDOCTYP>$' Input_file.txt
```

prints

```
 <IDOCTYP>INVOIC02</IDOCTYP>
```

But how do I print out each line in the same grep command and generate the expected output? (tried separating with \| , but didn't work for me). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried separating with `|` (not `\|`)?

Comment: Tried this, but received an error -
    `grep '^.*<IDOCTYP>.*</IDOCTYP>$' | '^.*<MESTYP>.*</MESTYP>$' Input_file.txt`

Comment: The `|` must be part of the grep pattern (inside the quotes `''`)! The way you've shown it, the `|` symbol is not part of the pattern, but pipes the output of grep into another command named `'^.*<MESTYP>.*</MESTYP>$'` which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: @mkrieger1Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input in *test.xml* this will work in Bash.

```
grep  '<?xml\|<EDI_DC40>\|<DOCNUM>\|<IDOCTYP>\|<MESTYP>\|<SNDPOR>\|<EDI_DC40>\|<IDOC>\|<INVOIC02>' test.xml
```

or maybe ...

```
awk '/<?xml|<EDI_DC40>|<DOCNUM>|<IDOCTYP>|<MESTYP>|<SNDPOR>|<EDI_DC40>|<IDOC>|<INVOIC02>/'  test.xml
```

or also ...

```
awk '{ if ( $0 ~ /<?xml/ || $0 ~ /<EDI_DC40>/ || $0 ~ /<DOCNUM>/ || $0 ~ /<IDOCTYP>/ || $0 ~ /<MESTYP>/ || $0 ~ /<SNDPOR>/  || $0 ~ /<EDI_DC40>/ || $0 ~ /<IDOC>/ || $0 ~ /<INVOIC02>/ ) { print $0 } }' test.xml
```

Regards!